# order mismatch in Enumeration

Tags: java, enumeration

I am using Enumeration to read property file. Let's say values in my properties file are `lon2qaidxiat01.idx.local, master, 2015-02-13, 2015-02-28`. But when I try to read the same using `Enumeration`, it reads in random order like `2015-02-13,master,2015-02-28,lon2qaidxiat01.idx.local`.

Below is my code:

```
try {
    dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream("config/db.properties"));
    Enumeration enuKeys = dbProperties.elements();
    while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
        String value = dbProperties.getProperty(key);
        System.out.println(key);
        paramList.add(key);
    }
    ...
```

Please suggest how to read in sequential order using Enumeration.

Comment: Are you sure that the iterator should provide elements in some order?

Comment: Why not accessing the properties by their keys? Then the order how they are stored isn't important. E.g. `String hostName = dbProperties.get("host_name");`

Comment: its a hashmap. I don't see why ordering is important. u simply have keys and values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is just a `Hashtable` and does not guarantee any particular ordering. (There's no way to "fix" this. The ordering is lost at the call to `dbProperties.load`.)

If the ordering is important, use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or a `List` of key/value pairs (and roll your own loading routine) instead.

Comment: Properties class in built uses hashmap ,i am not sure how it can be converted into linkedhashmap.Any suggestions

Comment: It *can't*. As I said in my answer, there's no way to "fix" your code. If order is important, you have to roll your own solution. `Properties` simply does not support what you're after.